# C# storing value for T to convert back later

Tags: c#, json, generics

I don't know whether this is possible or not, but I am trying to somehow keep the Type of an object so that I can convert/cast that object back to it's original value later.

Basically I have a messaging engine using RabbitMQ. I receive a message which is a .net object with a JSON string within it which I need to serialize back to a .net object/class, but I want to keep it as generic as possible and would thus like to send the type of that claas either as a Type or as a string along with the object the message is contained in.

The object:

```
public Message
{
    public string JsonObject { get; set; }

    public Type MessageType { get; set; }
}
```

Serialization:

```
Message message = new Message(); // I actually receive message as a param in a Method

var message = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<message.MessageType>(futureMessage.JsonObject);
```

On the `<type>` part I am getting an error "The type or namespace name 'type' could not be found. (Are you missing or a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Then later on in my code:

```
DoSomething<T>(message);
```

Where T needs to be the same Type as which I stored in my Message object earlier on.

Is what I am trying to do even possible?

Edit: removed the unnecessary `Type type = Type.GetType(message.MessageType)` line

Edit: I need that generic type as I would like to send that type T to another method later on in my code.

Comment: can't you just use `object` as type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the generic method call using:

```
typeof(DoSomethingClass).GetMethod("DoSomething")
.MakeGenericMethod(message.MessageType).Invoke(InstanceOfDoSomething, message);
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to use another overload of `DeserializeObject`:

```
var message = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(
        futureMessage.JsonObject, message.MessageType);
```

To call a generic method with `message.MessageType` as a type parameter, you can use reflection or dynamic calls:

```
DoSomething((dynamic)message);
```

Note that in this case overload will be chosen at run time, as you're losing strong typing.

Comment: This does seem to work, but I actually do need to get that Generic Type T somehow, as I need to send it along to another method a little later on in my code.

Comment: @MrThursday Updated answer. I still don't completely understand what you're trying to achieve with this. I don't see how type parameters are actually used anywhere.

Comment: I have a very generic method that is shared throughout my code which accepts any object to be converted to JSON to be put into the RabbitMQ queue. I don't want to hard code types as this would limit my implementation. This part of code which I am working on now, is actually a message that I received earlier, which I wrap in another object to be kept in a separate queue and added back later to the original queue it came from.

Answer (score 0):

Use an overload:

```
 return (Message)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(message,message.GetType());
```

Answer (score 0):

As other have mentioned, It looks like your trying to use the generic JsonConvert.DeserializeObject() method which requires you to pass a generic type T.

You can call the DeserializeObject overload, passing the type.

http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/?topic=html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeObject_2.htm

Answer (score 0):

This is what i did some time ago when i needed to send data from the server to the client with json serialization, where the client wasn't able to know the type of the data.

On the server side:

```
var dataString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dataObject);
var dataType   = dataObject.GetType();
```

Send to the client a Tuple.

```
Tuple<dataString, dataType>
```

On the client side:

```
var dataObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Tuple.Item1, Tuple.Item2);
```

This worked just fine for me...